# Learning to rank how to save model

Tags: tensorflow

I successfully managed to implement learning to rank by following the tutorial [TF-Ranking for sparse features](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/examples/handling_sparse_features.ipynb) using the ANTIQUE question answering dataset.

Now my goal is to successfully save the learned model to disk so that I can easily load it without training again. Due to the Tensorflow docs, the `estimator.export_saved_model()` method seems to be the way to go. But I can't wrap my head around how to tell Tensorflow how my feature structure looks like. Due to the [docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) the easiest way seems to be calling `tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn()`, which returns me the required inpur receiver function which I have to pass to the `export_saved_model` function. But how do I tell Tensorflow how my features from my learning to rank model look like? 
From my current understanding the model has context feature specs and example feature specs. So I guess I somehow have to combine those two specs into one feature description, which I then can pass to the `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` function?

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are on the right track;
You can get a `build_ranking_serving_input_receiver_fn` like this: (substitue context_feature_columns(...) and example_feature_columns(...) with defs you probably have for creating your own context and example structures for your training data):

```
def example_serving_input_fn():
    context_feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
        context_feature_columns(_VOCAB_PATHS).values())
    example_feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(
        list(example_feature_columns(_VOCAB_PATHS).values()))
    servingInputReceiver = tfr.data.build_ranking_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        data_format=tfr.data.ELWC,
        context_feature_spec=context_feature_spec,
        example_feature_spec=example_feature_spec,
        list_size=_LIST_SIZE,
        receiver_name="input_ranking_data",
        default_batch_size=None)
    return servingInputReceiver
```

And then pass this to `export_saved_model` like this:

```
ranker.export_saved_model('path_to_save_model', example_serving_input_fn())
```

(ranker here is a tf.estimator.Estimator, maybe you called this 'estimator' in your code)

```
    ranker = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        model_dir=_MODEL_DIR,
        config=run_config)
```